# Error "absent value where TRUE/FALSE is needed" when invoking sysreq::sysreq_commands

Tags: r, dependencies

I'm trying to get a single command to install all dependencies in an R `DESCRIPTION` file. Apparently, this command lists them so that they can be piped to a installation script:

```bash
Rscript -e "cat(sysreqs::sysreq_commands('DESCRIPTION'))"
```

Here's my DESCRIPTION file:

```
Package: ukrmoddata
Title: UKR Ministry of Defense data
Version: 0.0.2
Authors@R:
    person("JJ", "Merelo", email="jmerelo@ugr.es", role = c("aut", "cre"),
           comment = c(ORCID = "0000-0002-1385-9741 "))
Description: Necessary packages to generate initial charts
BugReports: https://github.com/JJ/raku-ukr-mod-data
License: GPL3
Encoding: UTF-8
Roxygen: list(markdown = TRUE)
RoxygenNote: 7.2.0
Depends:
    R (>= 4)
Imports:
  GGally,
  reshape2,
  arrow,
  dplyr,
  ggplot2,
  ggthemes,
  factoextra
```

And here's the error:

```
Error in if (rver == "r-devel" && os == "linux") { : 
  valor ausente donde TRUE/FALSE es necesario
Calls: cat ... get_cran_sysreqs -> make_url -> current_platform -> detect_platform
```

Which, in Spanish, is equivalent to "Absent value where TRUE/FALSE are needed".

I gather there's possibly some system requirement that's missing from DESCRIPTION, possibly related to one of the two variables there. However, I've tried to simply insert an `OS` entry and it has no effect; I haven't found any reference about this error or how to create a canonically complete `DESCRIPTION`

Comment: I don't get that error from the `DESCRIPTION` alone, but I do see `Entries with infeasible version number: R (>= 4)`, which is fixed by changing it to `R (>= 4.0.0)`. (Tested on win11, R-4.1.2, unfortunately not on linux atm.)

Comment: FYI, I don't get the idea that [`sysreqs`](https://github.com/r-hub/sysreqs) is still getting active development or even maintenance. https://github.com/r-hub/sysreqs/issues/19 (two years old) says that `sysreqs::detect_r_version()` returns `NA`, which will trigger an error such as that.

Comment: @r2evans any alternative? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: `devtools::install_deps` or `devtools::install_dev_deps`?

Comment: @r2evans looks like that works. I'll look for a way to make it unattended